# Azure Kubernetes - Overwrite the configmap values using environment variables?

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I am reading the configuration details from the configmap as shown below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: akv2k8s-test
  name: akv2k8s-test
data:
  Log_Level: Debug
  Alert_Email: Test@demo.com
```

pod definition

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: akv2k8s-test
  namespace: akv2k8s-test
spec:
  containers:
    - name: akv2k8s-env-test
      image: kavija/python-env-variable:latest
      envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: akv2k8s-test
```

and reading it with python

```
import os
loglevel = os.environ['Log_Level']
alertemail = os.environ['Alert_Email']
print("Running with Log Level: %s, Alert Email:%s" % (loglevel,alertemail))
```

I want to update the Configuration values while deploying, the below command fails

```
kubectl apply -f deploy.yaml --env="Log_Level=error"
```

How do I pass the environment variable while deploying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to update the configmap **while deplyoing**, The easiest way would be by getting the file content using cat and then update as you wish -

```sh
cat configmap.yaml |sed -e 's|Log_Level: Debug|Log_Level: error|' | kubectl apply -f -
```

In case you want to update the **existing configmap**, use `kubectl patch` command.

```sh
kubectl patch configmap/akv2k8s-test -n akv2k8s-test --type merge -p '{"data":{"Log_Level":"error"}}'
```